# How to List Multiple Figures in One Line of the List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way to condense multiple figures into one line for the List of Figures?  For instance, I have an appendix of measurements that are figures, which total about 600 images (multiple measurements made at multiple stations) that I don't necessarily want listed out individually, so can you force the List of Figures to read:

Figure B.1-B.30  Diagnostic Plots for station APZ....................302-310

Figure B.31-B40  Diagnostic Plots for station CRLZ...................311-320

etc.?

Comment: I don't know of a package that does it but if you wait until the document is done you can add `\nofiles` so that latex does not re-write the `.lof` file and hand edit it to compress the ranges.

Comment: this was asqed here but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The package `caption` make nearly what you want. Put your 600 figures between `\captionsetup[figure]{list=no}` and `\captionsetup[figure]{list=yes}` except the first one, that should have the "global caption" as the short caption. The difference is that this do not print the range of pages of the images group, but, I think that this is not necessary, as well as yo do not need at all the range of pages of each chapter, section, etc.

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\caption{A}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}\caption{B}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\caption[Many images]{An image}\end{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{list=no}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\caption{More images}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\caption{More images}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\caption{More images}\end{figure}
\captionsetup[figure]{list=yes}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-c}\caption{C}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```